# Time Complexity when if-else (if with a loop and else without a loop) is present

Tags: time-complexity

There have been some questions around this, but I never got an exact question or an answer which explains this:

( Pardon if this seems too silly)

What will be the time complexity of such a function?

```
void function(n){
  if(n %2 == 0)
    {
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        print();}
     }
  else if(n%2 ==1)
    {
     print();
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: The time complexity deals with *asymptotic* behavior, so when `n` goes to infinity.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks a lot. I missed a very basic point. But my doubt was something else. I will change the question.

Comment: Basically my doubt is when there are different ways possible to execute a program, what do we consider the time complexity, another example could be one of the "if" having some other functions called in it whereas the "if-else" might have nothing or functions with totally different time complexity than the one in previous "if".

Comment: that depends on whether you are talking about worst-case, average-case, best-case, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I get the best and worst, what about the average?

Comment: @Rushi, the Big O notation is about saying that the time required is less than or equal to the value, e.g., `O(n)`, times a constant factor as `n` approaches infinity. In your example, you would either have `1` or `n` (or roughly `n/2` for any two consecutive values of `n`). So all you can say is that it is less than or equal to `n` (times a factor). Thus, the time complexity is `O(n)` as stated in my answer below. Yes, the best case for some individual values of `n` is `1`, the worst case is `n`, and the average is approximately `n/2`. But the complexity class is `O(n)`.

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow Thanks a lot. I looked again at the definition and now it seems I was interpreting it differently before.

Comment: @Rushi, you are welcome. And if I answered your question, please accept my answer and upvote.

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow I accepted it, but cant actually upvote it requires about 15 reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) of the Big O notation, the time complexity of your `function(n)` is `O(n)`.